# UpdatePanelAnimationExtender - Animation to change Label.Text

Tags: asp.net, ajax, animation

I'm using UpdatePanelAnimationExtender with FadeOut/FadeIn Animations on a label.  Can I change the text of the label after the FadeOut?

```
<ajax:UpdatePanelAnimationExtender ID="upae" BehaviorID="animation" runat="server" TargetControlID="update">
            <Animations>
                <OnUpdating>
                    <Sequence>
                    </Sequence>
                </OnUpdating>
                <OnUpdated>
                    <Sequence >
                        <FadeOut AnimationTarget="lblUpdate1" duration="1.0" Fps="24" minimumOpacity="0" />
                        **<TextChangeAnimationHere? prop1="value1" prop2="value2" etc./>**
                        <FadeIn AnimationTarget="lblUpdate1" duration="1.0" Fps="24" minimumOpacity="0" />
                    </Sequence>
                </OnUpdated>
            </Animations>
        </ajax:UpdatePanelAnimationExtender>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution I came up with.

aspx code:

```
<form id="frmMain" runat="server">
    <ajax:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server" ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" />

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server" Text="Label">This is a test...</asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="myTimer" EventName="Tick" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

    <ajax:UpdatePanelAnimationExtender ID="upae" runat="server" TargetControlID="UpdatePanel1">
        <Animations>
            <OnUpdating>
                <Sequence>
                    <FadeOut AnimationTarget="lblMsg" duration="1.0" Fps="30" minimumOpacity="0" />
                </Sequence>
            </OnUpdating>
            <OnUpdated>
                <Sequence>
                    <FadeIn AnimationTarget="lblMsg" duration="1.0" Fps="30" minimumOpacity="0" />
                </Sequence>
            </OnUpdated>
        </Animations>
    </ajax:UpdatePanelAnimationExtender>

    <asp:Timer runat="server" Interval="6000" ID="myTimer" OnTick="myTimer_Tick" />
</form>
```

C# code-behind:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void myTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        lblMsg.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }   
}
```

Hat tip to [David Miyamasu](http://weblogs.asp.net/dmiyamasu/archive/2008/02/15/asp-net-ajax-slideshow-using-updatepanel-and-timer.aspx) for pointing me in the right direction.